# Could not find bctoolbox, linphone compile

Tags: linphone

my problem is compile belle-sip, mediastreamer2

this error: checking for BCTOOLBOX... no
configure: error: "Could not find bctoolbox (required dependency)"

how to install dependency bctoolbox?

MacOS 10.11.3
Linphone-android

Comment: Hi , You can use below link :
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-users/2016-05/msg00031.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to compile the bctoolbox first. Although I don't know anything about software compilation on MacOS, this works for Linux and could be similar.

```
git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/bctoolbox.git
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

Note that this SW is dependent on [CUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cunit/) and [mbedTLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) (currently is the dependence on version 2.1) or [polarssl](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/releases?after=beta-release). PolarSSL is the older version of mbedTLS but I'd use that because the related SW (Linphone, mediastreamer2 and belle-sip) do not recognize the newer one.

Comment: I can't pass libbctoolbox.la
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_bctbx_clean", referenced from:
      _bctbx_DestroyDHMContext in mbedtls.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libbctoolbox.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Well the installation procedure was quite changed since June 2016... Now I'd recommend you not to compile it with self-downloaded packages but use the prepare script for the whole project:
<code>
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-desktop --recursive && \
cd ./linphone-desktop && \
./prepare.py --use-system-dependencies --all-codecs --debug --list-cmake-variables && \
make
</code>